# Index PDF Documents to Solr - Error 500 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/MultiParts

Tags: java, solr, jetty, apache-tika

I'm trying to test an index of PDF documents to my Apache Solr Core.

I found the following instruction:
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_0/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html#configuring-the-extractingrequesthandler-in-solrconfig-xml

I added the neccessary **libraries** to my `solrconfig.xml`:

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../..}/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />
```

I also added the **RequestHandler** for indexing the PDF documents:

```
<requestHandler name="/update/extract"
            startup="lazy"
            class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="lowernames">true</str>
        <str name="fmap.content">_text_</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Afterwards, I restarted my Solr server and then tried to index a PDF document by using **curl**:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/test/update/extract?literal.id=doc1&commit=true' -F "myfile=@C:\Workspace\solr\solr-8.6.0\docs\pdf\test.pdf"
```

I expected the document to be indexed, but instead I get an `Error 500 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/MultiParts`:

```
> <html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
> content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/> <title>Error 500
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/eclipse/jetty/server/MultiParts</title> </head> <body><h2>HTTP
> ERROR 500 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/eclipse/jetty/server/MultiParts</h2> <table>
> <tr><th>URI:</th><td>/solr/test/update/extract</td></tr>
> <tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>500</td></tr>
> <tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/eclipse/jetty/server/MultiParts</td></tr>
> <tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>default</td></tr> <tr><th>CAUSED
> BY:</th><td>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/eclipse/jetty/server/MultiParts</td></tr> </table> <h3>Caused
> by:</h3><pre>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/eclipse/jetty/server/MultiParts
>         at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrRequestParsers.cleanupMultipartFiles(SolrRequestParsers.java:624)
>         at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:443)
>         at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:345)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1596)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:590)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1610)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1300)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1580)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1215)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:177)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
>         at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) </pre>
> 
> </body> </html>
```

Has anyone an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: is the jetty-server jar misssing? jetty-server-9.4.11.v20180605.jar?

Comment: Sounds like you have a mix of Jetty versions across your Jetty jar files.  Ensure that they are all running the same version.  If you use maven/gradle/ivy/etc, just add the [`jetty-bom`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-bom) properly to your build files to align the versions properly.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt, I'm getting exactly the same error with Solr 8.6.0 as it comes from the website. Suppose it uses embedded Jetty server, because I haven't installed it separately.

Comment: You have other `org.eclipse.jetty.server.` packaged classes being loaded (that's obvious from the stacktrace).  but the `org.eclipse.jetty.server.MultiParts` isn't loading.  that can only happen when you have multiple jetty-server jars on different versions in your classpath.

Comment: Thasn't look that the problem is because of different jetty server jars. Because a) there is no other jetty jars on the host and b) all jetty jars installed are from solr package and are from save version.

Comment: I can easily replicate this with duplicate jetty-server jars.  But not when I fix the jvm startup to have only 1 version of the jetty jars.

Comment: There is only one `./server/lib/jetty-server-9.4.27.v20200227.jar`. Though there are duplicate `jetty-client-*.jar`, `jetty-http-*.jar`, `jetty-util-*.jar` of same version, but in different sub folders.

When replicate do you duplicate same server jar, i.e. same version or are they different versions? What exactly you pass to the jvm to avoid it? What's your solr config? Can you replicate that examples work for you when solr 8.6 is installed https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/lucene/solr/8.6.0/solr-8.6.0.tgz?

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue of Solr 8.6.0 and Solr 8.6.1. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-14768

Downgrading Solr to 8.5.1 should solve it until the issue is fixed in a new Solr release.